# How to store multiple jpackage installations under the same parent directory?

Tags: java, installation, wix, windows-installer, jpackage

I have several applications that I finally turned into modular jars, and now, I want to package them with jpackage.

Since there are several applications, I want to bundle them all under the same parent directory, let's say `parent_directory`. I know that I can specify that as `--install-dir parent_directory/child_folder` for jpackage, according to this tutorial. https://dev.java/learn/jvm/tool/jpackage/

The problem is, if I specify the folder structure as above, then upon uninstallation, not only will `child_folder` get deleted, but so will `parent_directory`.

How do I get jpackage to only delete `child_folder` upon uninstallation?

EDIT - as a side note, I am aware of workarounds such as this -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67574903/10118965

I am not opposed to doing that, but I would consider that a last resort, and I want to exhaust my options before doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I jumped the gun.

As it turns out, Windows is smart enough to recognize that 2 installations share the same parent directory. So, it will only delete `parent_directory` if there is ***no other installation at that location***.

The reason I why I thought that it would delete `parent_directory` is because I tested it with a dummy folder, and then made the (false) assumption that windows would delete the whole `parent_directory` if there was another install there. But when I tested it with an actual, second installation, that assumption proved to be false.

I certainly have not stress tested this solution, but this works for my purposes, so I will accept it once the 2 days pass.